# Does pubsub topic schema validation support nested json?

Tags: nested, schema, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm having trouble creating an AVRO schema with a nested message.

e.g. JSON message,

```
{"metadata": {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}, "payload": {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}}
```

From the apache avro documentation I think this schema definition should work but it doesn't seem to:

```
    {
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Avro",
  "fields" : [
    {
      "name" : "metadata",
      "type" : "record",
      "fields": [
        {
          "type" : "string",
          "name" : "key1"
        },
        {
          "type" : "string",
          "name" : "key2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "payload",
      "type" : "record",
      "fields": [
        {
          "type" : "string",
          "name" : "key1"
        },
        {
          "type" : "string",
          "name" : "key2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is nesting just not supported?

Comment: Could you give an overview of your process and state what you aim is? Also, can you share any error message you have gotten and where you will use this schema? Since you mentioned that "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Avro schema definition you have provided isn't actually valid. The way to specify this schema would be:

```
{
   "type":"record",
   "name":"Avro",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"metadata",
         "type":{
            "type":"record",
            "name":"MetadataRecord",
            "fields":[
               {
                  "type":"string",
                  "name":"key1"
               },
               {
                  "type":"string",
                  "name":"key2"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"payload",
         "type":{
            "type":"record",
            "name":"PayloadRecord",
            "fields":[
               {
                  "type":"string",
                  "name":"key1"
               },
               {
                  "type":"string",
                  "name":"key2"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

There is still more working being done to ensure that the error messages returned on schema creation provide more details while the feature is in public preview.

You can see more details on the error if you run it through the avro parser in, say, Python:

```
import avro.io

schema = """
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Avro",
  "fields" : [
    {
      "name" : "metadata",
      "type" : "record",
      "fields": [
        {
          "type" : "string",
          "name" : "key1"
        },
        {
          "type" : "string",
          "name" : "key2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "payload",
      "type" : "record",
      "fields": [
        {
          "type" : "string",
          "name" : "key1"
        },
        {
          "type" : "string",
          "name" : "key2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
"""
parsed_schema = avro.schema.parse(schema)
```

Running this script will yield the error:

```
avro.schema.SchemaParseException: Type property "record" not a valid Avro schema: Could not make an Avro Schema object from record.
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution and all is working as expected now.